# Adding 1 day to day of week (Monday, Tuesday..)

Tags: php

Without knowing or using any kind of date, what's the best way to just add 1 day to the day of the week?

For example, I have `Monday` and I want to add `+1 Days`. Something like this

`echo ('Monday + 1 days');`

I tried with `date();` but couldn't find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: strtotime .... ? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: How did you try date?

Comment: `strtotime('Monday + 1 days');` ? doesn't seem to work..

Comment: `$tomorrow = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($date1 . "+1 days"));`

Comment: The problem is I don't have a date. And it may not always be tomorrow. I only have a day of the week as in `Tuesday` or `Friday`..

Comment: Sure strtotime works. You need to do a MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . https://3v4l.org/Oc3X0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
<?php
    echo date('l', strtotime('Monday + 1 day'));
```

We just use the `strtotime` logic of adding a time period and wrap it in a date format of l - which is full text representation of the day.

> l (lowercase 'L') A full textual representation of the day of the week    Sunday through Saturday

refs:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: There is no reason to answer a question that has been answered thousands of times.

Comment: @Andreas maybe, linked dupe uses a date - not necessarily a day. In that way tis different - but I guess it is more or less same principle - happy to rm if wanted?

Comment: Thank you so much :) I really did check a dozen other answers before asking but the others all used dates and I really couldn't figure it out. This really helped me and hopefully someone else too.

Comment: The duplicate uses strtotime and date. Nothing new. Visiting the manual about the two functions should be done prior to posting a question in my opinion. YMMV.

Comment: @Andreas what does YMMV mean? haha #acronymscrub - but deleting my answer seems a good way to go then :)

Comment: Your mileage may vary. Meaning you may have a different opinion or reality. It comes from the car industry where they can say a car can drive x miles on a tank, and they add YMMV. Because if it's uphill or city or someone always driving in first gear.

Comment: @Andreas ahh learn something new! Well, the principle is the same, so dupe away :) will rm in <5 mins

Comment: I don't think you can. It's accepted with +5.

Comment: @Andreas damn, sorry :/

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function in PHP that says "the day after Monday is Tuesday" without referring to a particular Monday (which is what strtotime would do). Of course, you may choose to not care that they refer to a particular Monday and Tuesday, since the pattern hasn't changed recently and will not change in the foreseeable future.

You can use an if statement or a switch-case statement. You can even make it work in a different language.

```
if ($date === "lundi") return "mardi";
if ($date === "mardi") return "mercredi";
// etc
```

Comment: could also make into a function ^^ :)